# How is the server and client supposed to interact

Tags: node.js

*I am just starting out with nodejs backend, so this might be a stupid question.*

**Little info**

I got my client (localhost:8080) and my server.js (localhost:3000). I made some routes for my `server.js` (see the file below).

**Question**

Now, if I try to access the route on my server e.g. `localhost:3000/users/4`, I get the expected result - 4 fake users are created. However if I try to append the postfix `users/4` to the client: (`localhost:8080/users/4`), I get an error! `Cannot GET /users/4`. Likewise I get an `cannot GET *SOMETHING*` if I try one of the other routes.

Have I misinterpreted something? Shouldn't I be able to append the route to the client url and then get the res (respons) back again? (as long as the server is running of course, or is that not how it works?). It would be lovely if someone could clarify how it works.

**routes.js** (I got all my routes in this one file)

```
    var faker = require("faker");

var appRouter = function (app) {


  app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Welcome to our restful API' });
  });

  app.get("/user", function (req, res) {
    var data = ({
      firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
      lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
      username: faker.internet.userName(),
      email: faker.internet.email()
    });
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });

 app.get("/users/:num", function (req, res) {
   var users = [];
   var num = req.params.num;

   if (isFinite(num) && num  > 0 ) {
     for (i = 0; i <= num-1; i++) {
       users.push({
           firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
           lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
           username: faker.internet.userName(),
           email: faker.internet.email()
        });
     }

     res.status(200).send(users);

   } else {
     res.status(400).send({ message: 'invalid number supplied' });
   }

 });
};

module.exports = appRouter;
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var routes = require("./routes/routes.js");
var app = express();

const server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

routes(app);

var server = app.listen(server_port, function () {
    console.log("app running on port.", server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: No, it's not how it works. Really not. I recommend you read a few books on the subject. Are you running the same code in server and "client"? What's the point of that? If not, how could you expect the two to do the same. Why on Earth would you need server _and_ client? Start with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works fine at (for example): http://127.0.0.1:8081/testit/35 ::

```
app.get('/testit/:bid', function(req, res){
 res.send('testit' + req.params.bid);
});
```

I would recommend, that you reduce your problem. So, start small with a route similar to mine and build from there.